# What does ^= do in jQuery (String)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$('[id^="save_"]').click(function () {});
```

How is the element being selected using id here?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors jQuery's syntax is almost the same.

Comment: What does [the jQuery selector documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selects every element whose id attribute value begins with "save_"

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your answer.

Comment: Sorry for the slip up!

Answer (score 0):

As quoted from the jQuery website:

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value
>   beginning exactly with a given string.

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

So if you have in your DOM two elements which are `#save_address` and `#save_cart` to select both of them by the same prefix `save_` you will use `$("[id^='save_']")`